# how to call an activity from a library android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

I'm trying to call an activity that is in the main project from a library

Library code

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, com.process.agenda.activity.MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Error:Circular reference between projects: :app -> :autenticadorCadastro -> :app

Main project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile project(':autenticadorCadastro')
}
```

Library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile project(path: ':app') // here throws the error
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to. If you needed to call into your main project from your library then the project is a dependency of the library which flips things the wrong way. If you're making a library it should only depend on itself and other libraries.

Comment: This is mostly true, but there's definite corner cases.  For example a UI widget that has a home button, but the home button changes based on the app.  It also depends on what type of library it is (some libraries are basically apps that just swap out some assets for white boxing, for example).

Comment: then there is no way to communicate again with the main?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the other methods of creating an intent.  Usually I do it by apk name and activity name (passed down from the calling app, or put into strings resources that are overridden by the app if its an internal only library).